# Display comma separated values for non existing rows in a table

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, csv

I have the below Dataset which looks like this.

```
t               mean        max     min     std     data_id
4/14/2010 0:00  12.6941 12.6941 12.6941 12.6941          1
4/14/2010 0:00  12.3851 12.3851 12.3851 12.3851          2
4/14/2010 0:10  12.389  12.389  12.389  12.389           1
4/14/2010 0:10  12.1836 12.1836 12.1836 12.1836          2
4/14/2010 0:10  11.3887 11.3887 11.3887 11.3887          3
```

I want to transform the data to

```
t,str_agg
'2010-04-14 00:00:00','12.6941','12.6941','12.6941','12.6941','12.3851','12.3851','12.3851','12.3851',,,,
'2010-04-14 00:10:00','12.3890','12.3890','12.3890','12.3890','12.1836','12.1836','12.1836','12.1836','11.3887','11.3887','11.3887','11.3887'
```

So if you look at the result there is no data for data_id 3 for t=4/14/2010 0:00 thus the result will have no values separated by commas.

I want this result in postgres. I have tried the below query:-

```
select t,string_agg(mean||','||max||','||min||','||std,',') within group(order by t)  
from table_name 
group by t  
order by t;
```

but this gives me the below result:-

```
t,str_agg
'2010-04-14 00:00:00','12.6941','12.6941','12.6941','12.6941','12.3851','12.3851','12.3851','12.3851'
'2010-04-14 00:10:00','12.3890','12.3890','12.3890','12.3890','12.1836','12.1836','12.1836','12.1836','11.3887','11.3887','11.3887','11.3887'
```

Comment: Are you using Oracle or Postgresql?

Comment: I am using postgres.

Comment: So the issue is just the extra commas at the end??? You can easily add those in with string manipulation

Comment: @DanielMarcus : how can i add them with my sql query?

Comment: @DanielMarcus : and it is not always at the end it can be any where.

Comment: @IftekharKhan . . . The way you have phrased your query, the results really cannot be anywhere.  Or rather, it doesn't make a difference.  The order is based on a constant, because you have `within group order by t` and `group by t` in the outer query.  So, the extra commas might as well go at the end, because their position is indeterminate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
WITH dataset AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM
        (
            VALUES
            ('2010-04-14T00:00'::TIMESTAMP, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1),
            ('2010-04-14T00:00'::TIMESTAMP, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2),
            ('2010-04-14T00:20'::TIMESTAMP, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1),
            ('2010-04-14T00:20'::TIMESTAMP, 4, 4, 4, 4, 2),
            ('2010-04-14T00:20'::TIMESTAMP, 5, 5, 5, 5, 3)
        ) AS data(t, mean, max, min, std, data_id)
),
timestamps AS (
    SELECT t FROM dataset GROUP BY t
),
data_id AS (
    SELECT data_id AS id FROM dataset GROUP BY data_id
),
dataset_full AS (
    SELECT
        coalesce(dataset.t, ts.t) AS t,
        mean,
        max,
        min,
        std,
        data_id
    FROM
--         generate_series(
--                 (SELECT min(t) FROM dataset),
--                 (SELECT max(t) FROM dataset),
--                 '10 minutes')
--             AS ts(t)
        timestamps AS ts
--        CROSS JOIN generate_series(
--                       (SELECT min(data_id) FROM dataset),
--                       (SELECT max(data_id) FROM dataset))
--            AS data_id(id)
        CROSS JOIN data_id
        LEFT JOIN dataset ON ts.t = dataset.t AND data_id.id = dataset.data_id
)
SELECT
    t,
    string_agg(concat(mean, ',', max, ',', min, ',', std), ',')
FROM dataset_full
GROUP BY t
ORDER BY t;
```

- The *dataset* CTE (common table expression) is there just in place of your table.
- *dataset_full* adds all the missing rows by generating a row for every combination of a 10m interval and data_id value. *dataset* is then LEFT JOINed to it, meaning there are now NULL values for those previously non-existent rows. NULL values then get converted to empty string in string_agg, resulting in what you want.

**EDIT**
I changed it per request by the OP in comments so that it only returns rows with timestamps that exist in the original dataset.

**EDIT 2**
I changed it per another request by OP to only use data_ids from the dataset.

Comment: The issue with your code is that if i change all ''2010-04-14T00:10' to '2010-04-14T00:20' then in that case i will be getting extra line as shown below :-  '2010-04-14 00:10:00',',,,,,,,,,,,'

Comment: That's not an issue, that's what I understood you wanted :-) If you have different intervals than 10m, then just change the interval in the first generate_series to whatever you need there.

Comment: Or if you want just the timestamps that are in your dataset, then instead of the first generate_series (the times(time)), use another cte that selects all the timestamps from the dataset.

Comment: I was not able to do it. Can you please help me with that?

Comment: I updated the answer so that it works as you asked for. @Iftekhar Khan

Comment: There is one issue with the code that you have provided. This records data between min(data_id) and max(data_id) but i want the data_id to be specific .. Something like 1,2 and 13 only.

Comment: @Sunny I edited the answer so that it only takes data_ids that are present in the dataset. But come on, this is completely analogy to the previous edit, you should be able to figure simple stuff like this yourself!